# Can't echo $CATALINA_HOME

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

When I `echo $CATALINA_HOME` I get a blank line, but when I `ls $CATALINA_HOME` I correctly get a listing of the directory. Why can't I echo it? I am running Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `ls $CATALINA_HOME` is expanding `$CATALINA_HOME` to the empty string and accordingly simply doing `ls` (or `ls .` to be pedantic).  Either you're in the correct directory already or you're not getting what you think you are.

Comment: Ah! Of course. Turns out I am not getting what I thought I was. I have a regular Tomcat setup - any idea why these environment variables aren't being set? Or maybe they are just set for a tomcat user/group? Because it seems to be working correctly, I was just curious.

Comment: I would guess they're set right by whatever starts up Tomcat, but not for anything else. But I don't know Tomcat so it's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

There is no [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) $CATALINA_HOME unless you defined it beforehand. You can see that the output of ls will always display the current directory (that is not necessarily your home directory!)  if invoked with an empty or undefinded variable:

```
 ls $BLABLABLA
```

The current user's home directory is stored in $HOME:

```
echo $HOME
```

The current user name is stored in $USER:

```
echo $USER
```

Only invoking `ls` with $HOME will always list the contents of the current user's home directory.